# "Enable Macros" in other workbooks?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following macro to refresh all of the data linkages in 4 workbooks that my "reports" workbook is dependent on.  I am running into a problem where the data is not updating accurately unless the "Enable Macros" button has been clicked in the Q1 - Q4 workbooks previously on the user's computer.

I tried recording a new macro where I click on the "enable macros" button in the workbooks when I open them but it does not record.

From my looking around on the forum here, I see you cannot force a user to enable macros.  Is there something else I can do, or add in here to make this work?

(Note: Directories and filepaths have been changed to generic names)

```
Sub Refresh_Quarterly()
'
' Refresh_Quarterly Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+r
'
    ChDir "Network Location 2018"
    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "2018 Q1 Data Sheet.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=3
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    ChDir "Network Location 2018"
    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "2018 Q2 Data Sheet.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=3
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    ChDir "Network Location 2018"
    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "2018 Q3 Data Sheet.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=3
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    ChDir "Network Location 2018"
    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "2018 Q4 Data Sheet.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=3
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
    MsgBox "Thank you for refreshing all data linkages.  2018 Reports is now ready to use"
End Sub
```

Comment: Call users on the phone and explain for this to work they need to select `Enable all macros` in the trust center options. Most will comply with a gentle conversation of why it's needed (and when to not trust an Excel file so they don't open random ones).

Comment: Basicaly the user has to make all of the macros to be enabled into his own workbooks. I am doing like this with my colleagues. I made a folder on their Desktop and put the folder in the Trusted Locations. Then they have to change the settings to allow all the time the macros from that folder to be enabled, so they have to enable all the macros and that is it.

Comment: The "2018 reports' file is on a network drive, and can be accessed by anyone in our department.  So if I understand correctly, if I go around and get all the people who would access this file (and the files it depends on) to make the folder it all is in a Trusted Location, then it should work without having to enable macros every time?

Comment: I always thought that "manual" macro security settings were not by default enforced when opening a file through automation: see for example https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-automationsecurity-property-excel  Note the default security setting for any file opened via automation is "enable"